# "Was victim" vs "was the victim."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What's the difference between the two? Do they have the same meaning or different meanings?

Example sentence:

> He was (the) victim of one of the biggest ironies that could befall someone.

Comment: I would say *he was victim **to** something*, without an article, but *he was victim **of** something* sounds very strange. I don't know why the preposition makes a difference, but it does. (Just general usage.) I can't think of any grammatical reason for it. Note you can also use *a* rather than *the*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use:

> the victim of
>
> victim to

“The victim” implies that the person is the single victim of something; we’re labelling the person. With “victim to”, we’re implying more the state of being with regard to victimhood.

Consider the following, where it would make no sense to use “the”:

> He fell victim to...

The above implies the person “fell into” a state of victimhood, with “to” indicating the perpetrator or condition.

With your example, I think “victim to” would be more appropriate (notice how my preceding example correlates with your example’s use of the word “befall”).